# Undefined reference to function when using shared library in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I have some problems to use a custom shared library, since I get undefined reference errors for **some** functions from two of many other source files.

If I compile the whole project with main file (release:), everything works just fine. But if I create a shared library (lib:) and use this library with the main file (all:), those compile time errors occur.

Here is a snippet of my makefile

```
release:
   $(CC) -Wall -s -w $(INCLUDES) $(LIBRARY) $(SRC) mainfile.cpp $(OCV) $(BOOST) $(GLOG) $(GFLAGS) -o test.exe
lib:
   $(CC) -fPIC $(INCLUDES) $(LIBRARY) -c $(SRC) $(OCV) $(BOOST) $(GLOG) $(GFLAGS) 
   mv *.o obj/
   $(CC) -shared -o libOutput.so obj/*.o
all:
   $(CC) -Wall -s -w $(INCLUDES) $(LIBRARY) mainfile.cpp -L/path/to/lib/ -lOutput $(OCV) $(BOOST) $(GLOG) $(GFLAGS) -o project.exe
```

Since there is no error during compilation using the release-option, I'm assuming that there is a linker specific problem.

I inspected the specific object files using *GNU Binary Utilities*

```
nm -C obj/specific.o | grep functionName
```

with no results. I did the same for the shared library, but this time with the following result,

```
U functionName(std::vector<int>)
```

which means that the function is unknown.

Do you have any suggestions, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is it a compile time or a runtime error?

Comment: It's a compile time error

Comment: What's the error ?